# How to make the test_train split in sklearn? Type Error returned

Tags: python, dataframe, typeerror, countvectorizer

I'm new at pyspark and I'm trying to split my dataframe on test and train set to apply naive bayes then.

I have a dataframe that consists of two columns: text and stars (label).

There is my code:

```
df3= df2.select( "text", "stars")
text_train, text_test, label_train, label_test = train_test_split(df3['text'], df3['stars'], random_state = 1)
```

Unfortunately I got Type Error: 
`TypeError: object of type 'Column' has no len()`

I'm using scikit-learn to make the split.

Could you please tell me how can I fix it?

Comment: can you try to print the contents of `df3`? `print(df3.head()))`

Comment: I got the first row printed

Comment: I don't think the `.select` method works like you are using it here. Can you try to just run this: `text_train, text_test, label_train, label_test = train_test_split(df2['text'], df2['stars'], random_state = 1)`.

Comment: I got the same error unfortunately :( nothing changed

Comment: Scikit Learn takes in `numpy` based matrices. You can't run it with a Pyspark dataframe and expect it to work out of the box. Convert your Pyspark dataframe into a Pandas dataframe instead.

Comment: Oh, it is a Pyspark dataframe. My bad! Ignore anything I said